# PUT doesn't work on POSTMAN but okay when called from front-end

Tags: node.js, rest, aws-lambda, postman

I have the following lambda function that works when called from the front-end React app:

```
// Update a contact
    module.exports.updateContact = async (event, _context) => {
      const id = event.pathParameters.id;
      const body = JSON.parse(event.body);
      const paramName = body.paramName;
      const paramValue = body.paramValue;

  const params = {
    Key: {
      id: id
    },
    TableName: contactsTable,
    ConditionExpression: 'attribute_exists(id)',
    UpdateExpression: 'set ' + paramName + ' = :v',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':v': paramValue,
    },
    ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW'
  };

    try {
      const res = await db.update(params).promise();
    }
    catch (err){
      console.log(err);
      return err;
    }
    const response = {
          statusCode: 200,    
          headers: {    
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',    
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,    
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            status: 'updated!',
            [paramName]: paramValue,
          }),
    };  
    return response;
};
```

But it fails with status code 502 & '`InternalServerErrorException`' message when called from Postman.
[image]

I tried to solve it with one of the suggestions found on stackoverflow with method override:
[image]

It doesn't work and I'm now getting status code 403 and '`MissingAuthenticationTokenException`'.
[image]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, seeking some guidance. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the API endpoint has an Authorizer configured on the API Gateway and the front end is sending the correct credentials, while the Postman configuration is not.

I would suggest to use the browser dev tools selecting the PUT request and copy it as cUrl:

[image]

then you can paste the copied cUrl command into the Postman request. It will prefill all the parameters: method, body and the headers.

hope this help

Comment: Thank you it worked! Turned out that I wasn't sending the parameters in the right format.